# Complete the logical sequence

Tags: pattern

Could anyone help me with solving this one?

[image]

Comment: Do you know the answer?

Comment: @Arkku not really.

Answer (score 5):

A guess:

> ←↑↘︎

Rationale:

> On each row the leftmost arrow is vertical in one column, horizontal in one column, and diagonal in one column. The middle arrow is always vertical. The rightmost arrow alternates between opposite directions.
>
>  Out of the alternatives, only the top right corner satisfies all three patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> Its 2nd from left bottom row.

Reason:

> Each row is transformed using the following rules.
>
>   Start at the top row and proceed downwards, using following.
>
>  1) The first arrow rotates 45 degrees clockwise
>  2) The middle arrow is 180 rotated clockwise.
>  3) Third arrow is 90 degree rotated clockwise

Comment: How do you get to the bottom row from the middle row following this algorithm? (The first two from the left of bottom row don't seem to match this pattern.)